# How do I trigger a css 3d animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, webkit

I'm working on a folding hide/show animation that I'd like to be able to trigger with javascript.

Here's the code and working example:
http://dabblet.com/gist/1654665

Of just the gist if you prefer:
https://gist.github.com/1654665

For the time-being, the open and close animations are within the same keyframe sets for simplicity's sake. If I can solve the problem of triggering the fold+unfold effect on click, then I can deal with splitting it up into 2 separate animations.

I've tried using jQuery's animate function but it doesn't seem to recognize the rotate and translate CSS3/webkit magic. I also tried moving the animation-name property to an .unfold state and using jQuery to set `$("#stage").toggleClass("do_animation");`

```
#stage.do_animation #topfold{
  animation-name: topfold;
}
#stage.do_animation #bottomfold{
  animation-name: bottomfold;
}
#stage.do_animation{
  animation-name: collapse_expand;
}
```

...I have some other ideas that I plan on trying, but I thought I'd throw the question out there since I'm sure many of you have much more experience with this sort of thing.

---

Lastly, if anyone out there is interested in working on this with me to bring it to a state where it can be easily used to hide/show all kinds of content, I'd love the company. The animation is inspired by the one used to [expand quoted text](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3pJyULv__k) in OSX Mail and I'd love to see it through to that level of quality.

Comment: Do you still need this?  I am working on a jQuery plugin for this kind of animation. If needed I can show my progress. Otherwise I will wait till the plugin is ready for public.

Comment: @pixelass That'd be great. The project was for fun more than anything, but it's still something that I'm interested in. I'd especially love to see a version that's content agnostic.

Comment: I have a fully dynamic version (using 2d trasnsforms with skew though.. so the 3d view is an angle). I have range controllers to control fold-section height an fold percentage "live". I will post an answer with one of my first versions. (without the live change range controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Answer on request.

Please see the fiddle for more detail..

(my current version is using 2d-transforms.. I made this before I found this question)
this might help though..
http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/a74Eu/32/

**I am working on a jQuery plugin for this.**

my current jQuery (please look at the fiddle)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('button#folder'),
        buttonSet = $('button#setter'),
        fold = $('.wrapper'),
        odd = $('.wrapper .part:nth-child(1)'),
        even = $('.wrapper .part:nth-child(2)'),
        gVal = $('input.perc').attr('value') / 25,
        hVal = $('input.heig').attr('value'),
        shadHeight = hVal / 2,
        closed = false;

    buttonSet.click(function() {
        gVal = $('input.perc').attr('value') / 25;
        hVal = $('input.heig').attr('value');
        fold.find('.part').css('height',hVal + 'px');
        shadHeight = hVal / 2;
    });
    button.click(function() {

        var rePos = hVal / 4 * gVal,
            rePosWrap = rePos * 2,
            newDeg = 90 / 4 * gVal,
            newScal = 1 - (1 / 4 * gVal);
        if (closed) {
            button.text('fold');
           fold.css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY(0px) translateX(0px)');
           odd.css('-webkit-transform', 'skewX(0deg) scaleY(1)').css('box-shadow','-4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0) inset, 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0) inset');
           even.css('-webkit-transform', 'skewX(0deg) scaleY(1)').css('box-shadow','-4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0) inset, 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0) inset');
            $(".partwrap").each(function() {
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY(0px)');
            });
            fold.toggleClass('close');
            closed = false;
        } else {
            button.text('unfold');
            fold.css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY(-' + rePos + 'px) translateX(' + rePos + 'px)');
            odd.css('-webkit-transform', 'skewX(' + newDeg + 'deg) scaleY(' + newScal + ')').css('box-shadow','-4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 ' + shadHeight + 'px ' + shadHeight + 'px rgba(111,111,111,0.2) inset, 0 -' + shadHeight + 'px ' + shadHeight + 'px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset');
            even.css('-webkit-transform', 'skewX(-' + newDeg + 'deg) scaleY(' + newScal + ')').css('box-shadow','-4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 ' + shadHeight + 'px ' + shadHeight + 'px rgba(111,111,111,0.2) inset, 0 -' + shadHeight + 'px ' + shadHeight + 'px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset');

            $(".partwrap").each(function() {
                var goUp = $(".partwrap").index(this) * rePosWrap;
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY(-' + goUp + 'px)');
            });
            fold.toggleClass('close');
            closed = true;
            console.log('-webkit-transform', 'skewX(' + newDeg + 'deg) scaleY(' + newScal + ')');

        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing, this is quite nice. After a quick pass through I found some problems though. I'd like to dig into it more later, but I'm at work at the moment. Anyway, the folding should happen inwards rather than sideways so it doesn't occlude other content. Also, the wrapper should be transformed to shrink vertically so content following the collapsable section fills in the space. Set .wrapper { background: rgba(12,56,78,.5); } in your css and you'll see some of the problems.

Comment: like I said.. I'am still working on it.. you can play around with this real time version using range elements. (still very alpha though). http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/GK6hM/embedded/result/  but it dynamically changes the shadow intensity, so it's a lot more realistic.

Answer (score 0):

ah good way I find to trigger css3 animations it's to set your base state of animation in your stylesheet (where you add css3 animation properties)

```
#element {
   1stStateofCSS3Animation;
}
```

and you can easily trigger them with something like this...

```
$(element).click(function() {

$(element).css(2ndStateofCSS3Animation);

}
```

I usally use this when i want the entire div triggers the action and not only my text or images with anchor

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to change the CSS like this:

```
/* Fold/Unfold animation
Now with gradients and expanding container!
*/
body { margin-top: 200px; }

@keyframes topfold {
  0%  {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50%  {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 100px 100px #AAA;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bottomfold {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-120px) translateZ(-120px) rotateX(90deg);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 100px 100px #CCC;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes collapse_expand {
  0% {
    height: 240px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 240px;
  }
}

#stage {
  perspective: 400px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
  /*background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
}
#stage.test{
  animation-name: collapse_expand;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.fold {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  /*border: 1px dashed black;*/
}

p {
  color: #333;
  font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#stage.test #topfold {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  animation-name: topfold;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}   

#stage.test #bottomfold {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  animation-name: bottomfold;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Then in the JS what I did was some kind of:

```
document.getElementById('#stage').className = 'test';
```

And it worked for me. So the solution should be:

```
var stage = document.getElementById('#stage');
stage.onclick = function(e){this.className = 'test';};
```

Comment: I tried plugging your solution in a jsfiddle but wasn't able to get it to work as you claimed. Sorry for the slow reply, been working on other things.

Comment: Can you share please the jsfiddle?